# Qlik Sense Mashup Issue - List Box Toolbar is not showing when making selections

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, listbox, qliksense, mashup

**Goal:**
I am trying to show a List Box's toolbar when selecting one of its values in a Qlik Sense Mashup.

**Problem:**
Toolbar is not showing up.

**This is the code:**

```
</html>
...
<body>
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <div style="position:relative">
           <div id="QV20" style="width:100%;height:350px;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1300;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my current result:**

[Click here to show picture - Toolbar is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4j9M.png)

**This is what I am willing to achieve:**

[Click here to show picture - desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBLh3.png)

**I tried the following already:**

1) changing the top into multiple values --> no toolbar

2) Tried to change the z-index --> still no toolbar

3) Tried to change the height --> still no toolbar

4) even tried to use this:

```
 style="width: calc(100% - 4px); height: calc(8.33333% - 4px); left: calc(0% + 2px); top: calc(0% + 2px);"
```

this comes straight from Qlik Sense itself --> and still no toolbar

**PS:** as you can see, I am also using Bootstrap to create my Mashup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this and the toolbar will show up:**

```
.qv-filterpane
{
    overflow: visible;
}

.qv-selection-toolbar
{  
    position: absolute !important;  
}
```